# Nexmo - how to send messages to US/Canada based mobile numbers

Tags: vonage

I am trying to send SMS to the people all over the world using a non-registered short codes, but the sms cannot be delivered to US or Canada. How do I achieve this?

Is there an API to get information of the country using a phone number, so that I can know if the current number is of US or Canada's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Disclaimer: I work at Nexmo.)*

To identify US vs CA numbers you can use Nexmo's [Number Insight API](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/number-insight). Besides the country you can also get lots of info, landline or mobile, carrier, reachable or not, etc.

If you you want to send to the US using short codes without needing a short code yourself, you can also use our [US Short Codes API](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/US-shared-short-code-api). If your use case fits into what we support (two-factor authentication, alerts, or marketing).